# C program to count the occurrence of pattern string

Tags: c, string

Given a source string S and a pattern string P, count the number of times the pattern string P occurs in the source string S.

Input Format:
First line is the source string S s.t. 1 <= |S| <= 8192 characters
Second line is the pattern string P s.t. 1 <= |P| <= 8192 characters

Output Format:
Output a single integer containing the number of occurrences of pattern string P in source string S.

whats wrong in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i=0,j=0,k=0,loss=0,noss=0;
 char ms[8192],ss[8192];
 scanf("%s",&ms);
 scanf("%s",&ss);
 while(ss[loss]!='\0')
  {
    loss=loss+1;

      }
     while(ms[i]!='\0')
      {
       j=0;
       if(ms[i]==ss[0])
        {
          j=j+1;
          k=i+1;
          while(ss[j]!='\0')
           {
             if(ms[k]==ss[j])
                j++;
             else
                break;
           }
          if(j==loss-1)noss++;
        }
       i++;
      }
      printf("%d",noss);
      return(0);

     }
```

**Test Case 1**

*Input*:  mississippi
          issi

*Expected output*: 2

*Actual output*: 2

**Test Case 2**

*Input*: ouagadougou
         ou

*Expected output*: 3

*Actual output*: 0

Comment: Remove those ampersands from those two scanfs

Comment: and just to be clear, that's not the issue. :)

Comment: "What's wrong" ? Isn't that what **you** are supposed to know, and we are supposed to make it right ?

Comment: I really hope these variable names are meaning something to you...

Comment: @EugeneSh. `noss == number of sub strings`, you see. Can you guess about the `loss` here ?:P

Comment: @harsha is this some semester project related or homework? I can't remember actually the post but very very recently I've seen the same "mississippi issi" case here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh http://stackoverflow.com/q/31950695/3049655 ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh  it seems companies are asking these questions in there written test ;)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, just for answer sake try this. See the difference in line#25-28 and 32.

```
 18        if(ms[i]==ss[0])
 19         {
 20           j=j+1;
 21           k=i+1;
 22           while(ss[j]!='\0')
 23            {
 24              if(ms[k]==ss[j])
 25 {
 26                 j++;
 27 k++;
 28 }
 29              else
 30                 break;
 31            }
 32 if(j==loss)noss++;
 33         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int PatternCount2(string s)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool mark = false;
    bool inword = false;
    
    for(char c: s) {
        if(c == '1') {
            if(mark && inword) {
                // found pattren
                result++;
                // reset inword
                inword = false;
            }
            mark = true;
        }
 
       if(c == '0' && mark){   
            inword = true;
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```